# Convert variable name to string

Tags: objective-c

How can I convert a **variable name** into a **string**?

Example:

From this:

```
NSString *someVariable
int otherVariable
```

I want to get a NSString with the actual name of the variable, no matter what type it is.
So, for the two variables above I would want to get their names (**someVariable**, **otherVariable**).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem with this code snippet:

Import the objc runtime
`#import <objc/runtime.h>`

and you can enumerate the properties with:

```
- (NSArray *)allProperties
{
    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);

    NSMutableArray *rv = [NSMutableArray array];

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
        [rv addObject:name];
    }

    free(properties);

    return rv;
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Just add " ... " around the variable name. i.e.

```
"someVariable"
"otherVariable"
```

to get the string (as a `const char*`.) If you want an `NSString*`, use

```
@"someVariable"
@"otherVariable"
```

Within a macro, you can use the construction `#...` to put the quote ... unquote around a macro variable, e.g.

```
#define MyLog(var) NSLog(@"%s=%@", #var, var)
```

so that

```
MyLog(foo);
```

is expanded to

```
NSLog(@"%s=%@", "foo", foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

These are C declarations, and C does not have the introspection capability to give you what you want.

You could probably write a preprocessor macro that would both declare a variable and also declare and initialize a second variable with the name of the first.

But this begs the question of why you need this level of introspection at all.

Comment: I'm reading some nodes from a json and I use the node names as variables in my application. I do this because I have for each node three similar names (node, node_waiting, node_rejected) so I'm hopping to use the variable name in such a way that I don't have to create 3 times the number of variables.